# Detect ASP.Net Asynchronous PostBack using PageRequestManager Events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to Detect ASP.Net Asynchronous PostBack and its settings like control and UpdatePanel that caused PostBack and the using `PageRequestManager` Events in JavaScript  and here is an example of what I am doing :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "Button1" EventName = "Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//////////////
//some javascript code 
/////////////
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to use JavaScript to detect this post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, e) {
        //Event raised when the Async Postback is started.

        //Detect whether the request is Async
        var isAsync = sender._postBackSettings.async;

        //Detect Id of the control that caused the postback.
        var controlId = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;

        //Id of the updatepanel that caused the postback
        var updatePanelId = sender._postBackSettings.panelID.split('|')[0];
    });
}
prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
        //Event Raised when the Async Postback is completed.
    }
});
```

put this and tel me the result :) you know that the same article is posted in this link with the same code :
http://www.aspsnippets.com/

if you do not understand ask for explaining :)